# Fundamental theorem of calculus with chain rule

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, chain-rule

I'm trying to prove that if we define
$$F(x) =\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)} f(t) dt$$
If $f$ is continous in $x_0$, $g(x)$, $h(x)$ are differentiable in $x_0$, and the range of a neighbourhood of $h(x_0)$ and $g(x_0)$ is included in the domain of $f$ then

$F'(x_0)=f(h(x_0))h'(x_0)-f(g(x_0))g'(x_0)$

I tried to divide the proof in
$g(x_0)<h(x_0)$, $h(x_0)<g(x_0)$ and $g(x_0)=h(x_0)$

When $g(x_0)<h(x_0)$, what I did is define

$$M(y) = \int _a^y f(t) dt$$
$$N(y) = \int_y^a f(t) dt$$

And I have proven that if $f$ is continous in $x_0$:

$$M'(x_0)=f(x_0)$$
$$N'(x_0)=-f(x_0)$$

As $F(x) = M(h(x)) + N(g(x)) $ when $g(x)<h(x)$ and this holds in a neighbourhood of $x_0$, $(x_0-ε,x_0+ε)$ as $g$ and $h$ are continous in $x_0$, it follows that $$F'(x_0)=f(h(x_0))h'(x_0)-f(g(x_0))g'(x_0)$$

Similarly we prove the case when $h(x_0)<g(x_0)$, using that $$F(x) =\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)} f(t) dt =-\int_{h(x)}^{g(x)} f(t) dt$$

The problem comes when $g(x_0)=h(x_0)$, using $$F(x_0)= \int_{g(x_0)}^{g(x_0)} f(t) dt = 0$$

as I don't know what happen in a neighbourhood of $x_0$

I tried to do $$F'(x_0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(x_0+h)-F(x_0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(x_0+h)}{h}$$

but I didn't get anything and I don't know what else should I do.

---

Edit:

I change the way to prove it and, with the same inicial conditions, I define 
$$M(y) = \int _a^y f(t) dt$$

We also have that if $f$ is continous in $x_0$, then:

$$M'(x_0)=f(x_0)$$

Now we have $F(x_0)=M(h(x_0))-M(g(x_0))$ and this holds for all 3 cases, so:
$$F'(x_0)=f(h(x_0))h'(x_0)-f(g(x_0))g'(x_0)$$

Comment: What are you allowed to use here? Are you allowed to use the ordinary fundamental theorem of calculus? It's easy if you use an antiderivative $G$ of $f$, because $F(x) =G(h(x)) - G(g(x)) $, and you can just use the chain rule.

Comment: Do you mean using what I defined as M(x) to say F(x) = M(h(x)) - M(g(x))???   It may work, but what if  "a" isn't in the domain of F, i.e. the least value in the domain of F is g(x)???

Comment: Why not set $a=g(x_0)$? And if you have defined the integral when $h(x_0)<g(x_0)$ then it seems to me you have defined definite integrals well enough so that you don’t need to consider separate cases for $<,$ $>,$ and $=.$

Comment: I used what I said in my comment before and that formula work for all 3 cases so it's better than all what I have done. What I finally do is say $a\leq min({g(x_0),h(x_0)}) $. So it could always be equal, and I think I can't just write $a= min({g(x_0),f(x_0)}) $ because I want a to be constant, not variable, so I want it to be the same value in a neighbourhood of $x_0$ not to change the formula so I can differentiate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the overuse of $\newcommand{d}{\,\mathrm d}x_0$ in the proof is problematic.
You shouldn't be looking at $f(x_0)$ at all;
$F'(x_0)$ can be equal to the desired formula even if $f(x_0)$ is undefined,
and conversely $f$ might be continuous at $x_0$ and yet
$F(x_0)$ is undefined (and therefore $F'(x_0)$ also is undefined).

For example, let $f(x) = \sqrt{1 - x^2},$ which is defined only on $[-1,1].$
Let $g(x) = x + 1$ and $h(x) = x + 2$.
Then $F'(x_0)=f(h(x_0))h'(x_0)-f(g(x_0))g'(x_0)$ when $x_0 = -\frac32,$ although
$f(x_0)$ is undefined;
but if $x_0 = \frac12,$ then $f$ is continuous at $x_0,$ and $g$ and $h$ both are differentiable at $x_0,$ but $f$ is undefined in the neighborhoods of $g(x_0)$
and $h(x_0),$ so $F(x_0)$ and $F'(x_0)$ are undefined.

Rather than looking at $f$ at $x_0,$ you need to be concerned with $f$ at $g(x_0),$ at $h(x_0),$ and at values in between in order for $F(x_0)$ even to be defined, and you should be concerned about neighborhoods of $g(x_0)$ and $h(x_0)$ in order to ensure that $F'(x_0)$ is defined.

One way to do this (but not necessarily the only way) is to require that $f$ be continuous on an open interval $I$ that includes both $g(x_0)$ and $h(x_0).$
As before, let $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ be differentiable at $x_0$ and define $F$ by
$$F(x) = \int_{g(x)}^{h(x)} f(t) \d t.$$

You could then proceed as follows:

Let $a \in I.$ Then
$$ \int_{g(x)}^{h(x)} f(t) \d t =
\int_a^{h(x)} f(t) \d t - \int_a^{g(x)} f(t) \d t. $$

Note that as long as we define this notation for definite integrals in the usual way so that $\int_a^b f(t) \d t = -\int_b^a f(t) \d t,$
the equation above is true no matter the order in which $g(x),$ $h(x),$ and $a$ appear on the number line.

Let $$ S(v) = \int_a^v f(t)\d t. $$
Then $S'(v) = f(v).$

Also,

$$ S(h(x)) = \int_a^{h(x)} f(t) \d t $$
and
$$ S(g(x)) = \int_a^{g(x)} f(t) \d t.$$

It follows that 
$$ F(x) =  S(h(x)) - S(g(x)) $$
and therefore
\begin{align}
F'(x_0) &= \left.\frac{\d}{\d x} S(h(x))\right|_{x=x_0}
 - \left.\frac{\d}{\d x} S(g(x))\right|_{x=x_0} \\
 &=  S'(h(x_0)) h'(x_0) - S'(g(x_0)) g'(x_0) \\
 &=  f(h(x_0)) h'(x_0) - f(g(x_0)) g'(x_0),
\end{align}

which was what we wanted to prove.

---

A note on the conditions of the theorem:

In most treatments of [the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalTheoremsofCalculus.html)
there is a "First Fundamental Theorem" and a "Second Fundamental Theorem." We use both of them in the proof above.

The Second Fundamental Theorem is invoked in order to be able to differentiate the function $S$ at $g(x_0)$ and at $h(x_0).$
This requires $f$ to be continuous in neighborhoods of $g(x_0)$ and $h(x_0).$

Note that in the statement of the Second Fundamental Theorem (at least as shown in the link above, and in many other places) it is not necessary that $a \leq v$ in order to be able to differentiate $S$ at $v.$ If your version of the Second Fundamental Theorem requires that $a \leq v$ then the proof will be slightly more complicated; a good first step would be to prove the usual version of the theorem first, because it is generally useful.
Once you have done that, you no longer have to worry about the relative order of $a,$ $g(x_0),$ and $h(x_0)$ on the number line. You can put $a$ between $g(x_0)$ and $h(x_0)$ if you like.

The First Fundamental Theorem is invoked implicitly in order to guarantee that the integrals in
$$ \int_{g(x)}^{h(x)} f(t) \d t =
\int_a^{h(x)} f(t) \d t - \int_a^{g(x)} f(t) \d t $$
can all be evaluated when $x = x_0.$ This requires $f$ to be continuous on the three closed intervals whose endpoints are pairs of numbers from the list $a,$ $g(x_0),$ and $h(x_0).$

In particular, for the first integral we want $f$ to be continuous on the closed interval whose endpoints are $g(x_0)$ and $h(x_0).$
Combine that with the fact that $f$ is continuous in neighborhoods of $g(x_0)$ and $h(x_0),$ and we have the fact that $f$ is continuous on some open interval including $g(x_0)$ and $h(x_0).$
If we just place $a$ somewhere in that interval, we also ensure that $f$ is continuous on the other two closed intervals we need.

---

Additional notes:

Since one of the necessary conditions is that $f$ be continuous on an open interval $I$ such that $g(x_0)\in I$ and $h(x_0)\in I,$
it is always possible to find a number $a\in I$ such that
$a < g(x_0)$ and $a < h(x_0).$
If you must use a definition of the definite integral notation
$\int_a^b f(t)\d t$ that is valid only when $a \leq b,$
you will need one of the conditions of the theorem to be
$g(x) \leq h(x)$ for $x$ in some neighborhood of $x_0,$
and therefore you will be able to choose $a$ such that
$a < g(x_0)\leq h(x_0)$ and all the integrals are defined according to this particularly narrow definition of the definite integral.
It is easy to do this: since you know $f$ must be continuous in some neighborhood of $x_0$, choose $\epsilon>0$ such that 
$(x_0 - \epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon)$ is a neighborhood on which $f$ is continuous, and set
$a = x_0 - \frac\epsilon2$ (or any other number in the interval 
$(x_0 - \epsilon, x_0)$).

If you want to be able to handle the case where $g(x_0) > h(x_0),$ however, I think it is hard to avoid using the typical definition of the definite integral, according to which 
$\int_b^a f(t)\d t = -\int_a^b f(t)\d t$.
That is, I think it would be hard to define the integral in such a way that this equation was not true and yet the theorem was true.
But if you have accepted the usual definition, you can choose $a$ anywhere in the interval $I$ and continue to use all the integrals shown in the proof above.
So I think a concern over the choice of $a$ within the interval $I$ is uncalled for if you also expect the theorem to be true in the case where $g(x_0) > h(x_0).$ That's why I made no effort to make $a < \min\{g(x_0), h(x_0)\},$
although it is easy to enforce that condition on $a$ if you want.

Comment: Ok, if I want that formula to be true when $f$ is continous at $x_0$ I need to add for example that the range of neighbourhoods of $g(x_0)$ and $h(x_0)$ must be included in the domain of $f$. And in that case I can take $a\leq min({inf(G)}, inf{H}) $ being G and H neighbourhoods of $g(x_0)$ and $h(x_0)$ so that a would be always in the domain of $f$.

Comment: Oh sorry, I deleted my last comment to change it. I said f to be continous in $x_0$ because the Second Fundamental Theorem is true in that case. What I proved is that if $F(x)=\int_{x}^{a} f(t) dt$ defined for an interval [b, a] and f is continous at $x_0$ then $F'(x_0)=-f(x_0)$. So in my first attempt to prove this I combined that formula with the one that says that if $G(x)=\int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt$ defined for an interval [a, b] and f is continous at $x_0$ then $G'(x_0)=-f(x_0)$. And in my recent attempt I'm trying to use what you've said but taking care that $a\leq g(x_0)$ and $a \leq h(x_0)$

Comment: OK, I think I see one of the points of confusion. When you write $F(x) = \int_x^a f(t)dt$ you're defining $F$ similarly (though not quite the same) as the way the symbol $F$ is used in the Second Fundamental Theorem. But in the theorem you have to prove, $F$ is defined in a very different way. Don't redefine $F$ inside your proof; introduce a different name when you need another function. That's why I wrote $S$ rather than $F$ in $S(v) = \int_a^v f(t)\,\mathrm d t.$

Comment: Ok, I edited my question with my new prove. But I'm still taking $a$ less than the neighbourhood of g(x₀) and h(x₀). So should I try  to prove that both Fundamental Theorem of Calculus holds for every interval [b, c] where $b\leq a \leq c$ ??? So that I can take any $a$ in the interval to prove this theorem